# What use in place of Annotations Configuration in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I used `AnnotationConfiguration` before but now is deprecated

```
AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Product.class);
factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

So now it's recommended to use `Configuration` insted, but still get some error:
[image: configuration].

How build a session factory now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are using some pretty new version, 4.0.0.CR4 perhaps? If so, then check the Javadoc of buildSessionFactory and it will tell you following:

```
 @deprecated Use {@link #buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry)} instead
```

No idea though is suggested replacement working, never used it.

Comment: Yep, my bad, I didn't check the latest version. Well, to be honest I'm not all that surprised that Hibernate pullled such a trick, as they tend to do this often. In the online doc however it still sais to use that method...

Comment: I guess online documentation matches more or less to some 3.6.x, current stable is anyway 3.6.7. Always worth of time spent to make sources of libraries (when available) browsable in IDE. Finding it especially useful when library is newer than ~2 years.

Comment: @Andrei Bodnarescu, I just accidentally had release candidate for other things. In general when version is not mentioned in question, I think current stable, as you assumed, is sensible default assumption.

Answer (score 1):

org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory() is not deprecated as far as I can see :

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#buildSessionFactory()

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.java.html

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html_single/

Are you sure it's not just Eclipse that's miss-reporting?

Comment: I don't know Andrei, I'm using the stable version of hibernate, don't know why is doing this.